# FreeBSD 9 ports: How to make quiet installations?

Tags: unix, freebsd, freebsd-ports

Just wondering how do I make ports installation - without config options (blue) window popup?

Assuming that I accept default options of the installation.

```
make install clean
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
BATCH=yes
```

to

```
/etc/make.conf
```

Alternatively, run `make install clean BATCH=yes`

Comment: I don't need it permanent. Just per the installation. Should `make install clean BATCH=yes` work?

Comment: yes it should work